# Benefits of square vs. triangular/hexagonal packing of cylindrical battery cells

Tags: batteries

A triangular or hexagonal packing (depending on your preference of terminology) of circles has a packing density of \$ \pi\sqrt3/6\$ \$ \approx\$ 91% ([see here at Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePacking.html), for example), whereas square packing gives a density of only \$ \pi /4 \approx\$ 79%.

With that is mind, what is the motivation for using square packing that is seen in some arrangements of cylindrical battery cells?

Comment: A battery pack isn't only about packing the cells, it is also about **connecting then together**. Connecting in straight lines looks easier to me.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie you can still do that in a hexagonal lattice.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Not as efficiently or regularly

Comment: @DKNguyen yes, you can. Hexagonal lattices have non-overlapping parallel lines through the center of the cells.

Comment: @MarcusMüller And? Doesn't change the fact you need irregular lengths as you approach the edges.

Comment: square packing allows better heat dissipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just speculation, so let's make this a wiki:

- ease of assembly,
- the need to surround with air for cooling purposes,
- opportunity to run fixation through the spaces
- opportunity to run signal or power conductors through the spaces
- weight distribution problems when packing batteries too densely in a light car,
- "crunch" zones that reduce the probability of combustion of batteries in a crash

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Marcus Müller's suggestions, consider that battery packs often end up as rectilinear prisms.  So take different stacking arrangements of **finite numbers of cells** (3, 4, 5, 6), stack them "square" and stack them "triangular", then calculate the area of the *smallest enclosing rectangle*.

Somewhere on the Internet there will be a guide, but for any number of circles, there's a crossover point between triangular stacking and square stacking being the most efficient use of space for finite numbers of cylinders.

Comment: Thanks, great answer and interesting topic. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2548513/maximum-number-of-circle-packing-into-a-rectangle) is also relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Speculation- packing volumetric density is not that important, mass is by far the important factor. Secondly, the need to have heat drawn out (especially during charging), typically through liquid coolant actively pumped through the battery bank.

Comment: But surely packing density affects the mass density, and therefore the overall mass?

Comment: @paddyr The mass of the batteries is determined by the number of batteries required, not by how tightly or loosely they are packed (at least to a first approximation).

Comment: Ah yes, of course, my comment was very unclear. I was thinking about the case where the overall volume is fixed and it's necessary to optimise the packing, which may or may not be a constraint in real battery designs.